# Where to see the number of character converted for Googles Cloud Text To Speech?

Tags: text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I like to know how many characters my Google Text To Speeach have converted? I like to know how close I am to limit of number of character converted before I get the bill.
Where can I see it in the Google Cloud dashboard ?